# How do you write Javascript to display MVC models with SignalR? (Javascript receives properties in parameter)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm working on adding SignalR to a working MVC application but I am not skilled in Javascript and I have no idea how to write it to display what I need. I saw a bunch of tutorials with the chat applications (sending a message) but that is not what I need.

What I want:
 Display a full model with all its components.
The program receives a file which adds a new property in the database. The property must be displayed with all its components.

**Here's an example of model (property) to display**

```
    public int WaterLevel { get; set; }

    public int WindSpeed { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfMachine { get; set; }

    public int FoodLevel { get; set; }
```

**The html page is the default html page that gets created with Visual studio:**
(This is what needs to be updated on the web page with the javascript)

```
<tbody>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr id="properties_display">
        <td id="waterLevel">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WaterLevel)
        </td>
        <td id="windSpeed">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WindSpeed)
        </td>
        <td id="numberMachine">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfMachine)
        </td>
        <td id="foodLevel">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodLevel)
        </td>
        <td id="number">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

**Watcher (On_Change):**

```
    private readonly IHubContext<PropertyHub> _hubContext;

    public MyFileWatcher(IHubContext<PropertyHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        //watcher stuff
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       DataAccess db = new DataAccess(MVCCoreAppDB);

       string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(e.FullPath);

       db.InsertData(filePath);

       var propData = db.LoadData();

       List<PropertyModel> properties = new List<PropertyModel>();

        foreach (var row in propData)
        {
            properties.Add(new PropertyModel
            {
                WaterLevel = row.WaterLevel,
                WindSpeed = row.WindSpeed,
                NumberOfMachine = row.NumberOfMachine,
                FoodLevel = row.FoodLevel
                Number = row.Number
            });
        }

       _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("onFileChange", properties);
    }
```

The watcher class is looking for changes in a folder. When a file is created or modified, it calls 3 methods. First, it inserts the data into the database and then, it loads that data from the database and change the type of it to be used.

Finally, it calls the hub for it to know that there are changes and that it needs to update the web page.

**This is what I tried and I get the real-time effect I need but it is not displaying the right thing:**

```
"use strict";

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/propertyHub")
    .build();

connection.on("onFileChange", function (properties) {
let tr = document.createElement("tr");
document.getElementById("properties_display").appendChild(tr);

let tdWaterLevel = document.createElement("td");
tdWaterLevel.textContent = properties[0];
document.getElementById("waterLevel").appendChild(tdWaterLevel);

let tdWindSpeed = document.createElement("td");
tdWindSpeed.textContent = properties[1];
document.getElementById("windSpeed").appendChild(tdWindSpeed);

let tdNumberMachine = document.createElement("td");
tdNumberMachine.textContent = properties[2];
document.getElementById("numberMachine").appendChild(tdNumberMachine);

let tdFoodLevel = document.createElement("td");
tdFoodLevel.textContent = properties[3];
document.getElementById("foodLevel").appendChild(tdFoodLevel);

let tdNumber = document.createElement("td");
tdNumber.textContent = properties[4];
document.getElementById("number").appendChild(tdNumber);
});

connection.start().then(function () { TestConnection(); }).catch(function(err)     
{
        return console.error(err.toString());
});


function TestConnection() {
     connection.invoke("GetConnectionId").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
     });
}
```

As it is right now, it's writing in the good columns but not at the end of the table and not writing values. It is writing object Object instead of a number. 
Furthermore, when I write in the javascript;

```
properties.WaterLevel  //For example
```

It is putting a blank space instead of writing something.

```
//It does the same thing if I write properties [0].WaterLevel
```

Output before update:
[image]
Output after update:
[image: Output after update:]
Output desired:
[image]
Properties value in debug after adding a new file:
[image]

Any idea of how to get the correct values at a good place?

Comment: Can you paste the output of "console.log(JSON.stringify(properties))" in the "onFileChange" function

Comment: Show us some output please what it display in the browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have, see the snippet.
Your JavaScript object is an array that contains a single object.

```js
var properties = [
  {
    "FoodLevel" : 48, 
    "Id":0, 
    "MachineID": "1234567",
    "Number" : 0,
    "NumberOfMachine" : 32,
    "WaterLevel" : 54,
    "WindSpeed" : 98
  }
]

let tbody = document.getElementById("tableBody")
let tr = document.createElement("tr");

let tdWaterLevel = document.createElement("td");
tdWaterLevel.innerHTML = properties[0].WaterLevel;
tr.appendChild(tdWaterLevel);

let tdWindSpeed = document.createElement("td");
tdWindSpeed.innerHTML = properties[0].WindSpeed;
tr.appendChild(tdWindSpeed);

let tdNumberOfMachine = document.createElement("td");
tdNumberOfMachine.innerHTML = properties[0].NumberOfMachine;
tr.appendChild(tdNumberOfMachine);

let tdFoodLevel = document.createElement("td");
tdFoodLevel.innerHTML = properties[0].FoodLevel;
tr.appendChild(tdFoodLevel);

let tdNumber = document.createElement("td");
tdNumber.innerHTML = properties[0].Number;
tr.appendChild(tdNumber);

tbody.appendChild(tr);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
   <th>Water Level</th>
   <th>Wind Sepeed</th>
   <th>Number Of Machines</th>
   <th>Food Level</th>
   <th>Number</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBody"> 
<!-- other razor code : for each x in model bla bla -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You are passing a list to the client where as I think you should only pass a single object of the list type, that way you dont have to access the object by index and can rather do: `properties.WaterLevel`

If it is your intention to update multiple objects at once (bear in mind , i'm not referring to your viewmodel that is alreaday rendered at this point), then you can loop the array and add each row sequentially.

So the life cycle is:

- render view with list of existing objects ( for each in model)
- client adds new item
- server broadcasts single new item to all clients
- client updates existing view with new single item

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the provided code but it's writing 'undefined' on the web page instead of displaying a number. Would you happen to know what's causing this? I changed my watcher a little bit so I'm getting only the last property added in the javascript and when I debug, I see the good values. But then it just writes undefined. It doesn't write anything if I use textContent instead of innerHTML.

Comment: Problem solved, it had to be camel case in the javascript. Something like that: properties.waterLevel. Thank you!

Comment: No probs, what journey it was!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused on how table and table rows works. First off the html should look more like this:

```
<tbody id="properties_display">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WaterLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WindSpeed)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberOfMachine)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

An `id` is supposed to be unique across the page, but you're creating a new row with all the same ids for each item in your Model. That's not good practice, and could lead to confusion of which element you want to add to. But this also means that each item in property should have its own row (tr) so you'll want to be inserting new rows instead of adding to any current ones which is what you're doing by referencing the ids in the javascript.

Actually, since you appear to be sending all the data back to the client on a change, then the simplest method of refresh would be to delete all current rows and add all new ones, something like this:

```
connection.on("onFileChange", function (properties) {
    let table = document.getElementById("properties_display");
    // Remove all existing rows
    while (table.firstChild) {
        table.removeChild(table.firstChild);
    }

    // Add a new row for each item in properties
    for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");

        let tdWaterLevel = document.createElement("td");
        tdWaterLevel.textContent = properties[i].waterLevel;
        tr.appendChild(tdWaterLevel);

        let tdWindSpeed = document.createElement("td");
        tdWindSpeed.textContent = properties[i].windSpeed;
        tr.appendChild(tdWindSpeed);

        let tdNumberMachine = document.createElement("td");
        tdNumberMachine.textContent = properties[i].numberMachine;
        tr.appendChild(tdNumberMachine);

        let tdFoodLevel = document.createElement("td");
        tdFoodLevel.textContent = properties[i].foodLevel;
        tr.appendChild(tdFoodLevel);

        let tdNumber = document.createElement("td");
        tdNumber.textContent = properties[i].number;
        tr.appendChild(tdNumber);

        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
});
```

I haven't tested it, but this is probably more along the lines of what you want. You're passing all your elements to the JavaScript so it needs to loop through all the items and get their individual properties. You may need to make sure your hub data is being correctly passed to the javascript. If it's not you might need to convert to Json on server before passing, but I think SignalR automatically handles that stuff.

You mentioned `properties.WaterLevel` doesn't return anything which makes sense since properties was an array, but if `properties[0].WaterLevel` then something else is probably the matter and I'd log the properties object in javascript to see what your server is actually passing to the browser.

As final remarks, deleting and replacing all rows is probably not the best idea. You might better reuse existing rows and add needed ones or simply pass only the changed elements from the server instead of all of them. Just some thoughts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it's very clear and helpful. I had some issue with my code that you noticed and so I had time to change some things. Now my InsertData returns the data that was just inserted and this way, I don't have to get an array. I can pass a single item, this way I can just do property.WaterLevel.

Comment: @Michaeldc glad it helped. I wasn't sure if you were hoping to get all rows or just the updated one.

Comment: Would you happen to know why no values are getting written on the web page? The property that I'm passing has the good values when I look it up in debug. When I use innerHTML it writes 'undefined' instead of writing nothing with textContent.
Can I write tdWaterLevel.textContent = property.WaterLevel? Or do I have to write something else?

Comment: @Michaeldc you mean you can see the good values when you look it up in debug after it has reached the JavaScript code? If you can see the values once it reaches the javascript code then it should be a matter of finding the right reference path to get the values

Comment: I did a console.log in my connection.on function and it shows the data in the console. So it gets corrupted in the property.WaterLevel call?

Comment: AAahhh it has to be camel case. It is case sensitive I guess. I looked in the console and saw that everything was in camel case and I adjusted everything and it works great! Thank you :))) I wish I could say that both of you answered my question but I'll have to checkmark the other one since he helped me a lot yesterday too! Both answers are good.